# [MySQL]How to sort by then group by?

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have table and data like this:

```
    id hour name
    1  0    a1
    1  1    a2
    1  2    a3
    1  3    a4
    2  1    a5
    2  1    a6 
    2  2    a7
    2  3    a8
    3  1    a9
    3  0    a10
    4  1    a11
    4  1    a12
    5  1    a13
    ……
```

I want to find some ids like (1,2,4 ....) and the ids' max(hour) and the unique id

result like:

```
id  hour  name
1   3     a4
2   3     a8
3   1     a9
4   1     a12
....
```

I try group by and sort by, but fail.
How to write it?
Thank you.

First time, when I write the question lose some info, so maybe some answer is not my want. So I update the question.
Sorry , I first use stackowverflow, sorry for my mistaken.

this my wrong sql:
select * from tb where id in(1,2,3,4) group by id order by hour desc.

I know how to write the right method:

this is wrong:

select id, max(hour) from tb group by tb;

this is right:

SELECT a.id, a.maxhour, b.name
FROM (
       SELECT id, max(hour) AS maxhour, name
       FROM tb
       where id in (1,2,3,4)
       GROUP BY id) a
       JOIN tb b ON a.id = b.id AND a.maxhour = b.hour

thank you all my friends.
your answer make me know how to do it

Comment: thank you all my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you just want to take the max hour value for each `id` group.  Here is one way to do this using analytic functions, assuming you are using MySQL 8+ or later:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY hour DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, hour
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY hour DESC;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: wa~~~It look like very cool. But my server use mysql 5.7....So maybe I can't use your method, is anyother method can run in mysql5.7?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use aggregate function `max()` and `group by`:

```
SELECT id, MAX(hour) AS mhour FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY mhour DESC
```

You can use a correlated subquery

```
    SELECT id, hour, name FROM tablename a
        WHERE CAST(LTRIM(REPLACE(name,'a','')) AS int) IN (SELECT MAX(CAST(LTRIM(REPLACE(name,'a','')) AS int)) FROM tablename b WHERE a.id=b.id)
    ORDER BY hour DESC
```

Comment: sorry, the result not my wanted. I update my question so that make the ask more clear.thank you

Comment: @kingdelee, I've updated my answer - I think you need the 2nd solution

Comment: i see your 2nd solution. But it didn't include sort by hour desc, It needn't change name, I add name column is to make display the sort result clear.

Comment: by the way,    id ln (1,2,3)

Comment: perhaps. I give you some ids (1,2,3). your sql give me. id:1, hour:3, name:a4; id:2, hour:3, name:a8; id:3, hour:1, name:a9

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,max(hour) as hour FROM table_name group by id order by id,hour desc;
```

Try this query.

Comment: sorry, the result not my wanted. I update my question so that make the ask more clear.thank you

Comment: Its okay, how do you taking the name? what is the relation ?

Comment: perhaps. I give you some ids (1,2,3).  your sql give me.  
id:1, hour:3, name:a4;       id:2, hour:3, name:a8;    id:3, hour:1, name:a9